# Axios GET request working in plain js but not working in react - CORS error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, cryptocurrency

When I make a GET request inside in react, I get `blocked by CORS policy` error. However if I make the same request inside vanilla js (a simple .js file) I get the appropriate response.

Here is my code in the react:

```
const axios = require('axios');

function getLatestPrice() {
  const config = {
    url: 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades?pair=ETHUSDT&since=1656322000',
    method: 'GET'
  };
  
  return axios(config);
}

exports.getLatestPrice = getLatestPrice;
```

I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades?pair=ETHUSDT&since=1656322000' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My code in vanilla js file

```
const axios = require('axios');

const url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades?pair=ETHUSDT&since=1656322000";


const config = {
  url: url,
  method: "GET"
};

axios(config).then(res => {
  console.log(res.data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Here I am getting the correct response. The postman request to the same is also working.

**(I am not controlling the API backend)**

Comment: you're right, the API does not issue CORS headers ... make the request from **your** server instead = `vanilla js file` ... interesting ... the endpoint you make a request to does not issue CORS headers, so, the "vanilla" code simply can't work in a browser - you are running that in a browser, right?

Comment: server blocks requests, you should use proxy or set Cross Origin Request Header to *

Comment: @Bravo I mean when i am making axios request in a react file, I am getting this error. But when I dont use react or make a postman request for the same request, I am getting the correct response

Comment: `when I don't use react` you mean don't use axios? in a browser, that request always fails since there's no CORS headers - so - can you show browser code that works - screw postman - it does not indicate if a browser can make the request anyway since postman is not subject to CORS restrictions

Comment: axios request is an async request. did you try using async await?